# Azure Newbie - setting up Virtual metal and installing a custom ISO

Tags: azure, iso

so I am given admin rights on our Azure instance and I want to set something up. A real newbie question. My project is this:

I have a machine spec. that my partner wants (4 CPU, 100GB Disk, 12GB mem and SS(SCSHSE)Network Element for machine 1 and 2 CPU, 40GB Disk 8GB mem for machine 2)

My partner has also given me a custom ISO to install on this "virtual metal".

My question is  - is there a quick start guide to doing this? I get that I could just use a machine image that already exists but the partner obviously wants his custom ISO running on my virtual metal....

Comment: Azure does not support ISO image, you should converted to VHD.

Comment: Hi, your VM is Linux or Windows?

Comment: The VM is Centos

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Azure currently supports only VHD.

According to your scenario, you should covert iso image to VHD. It is easy for you to do it. Please refer to this [link](https://mcloudinfo.wordpress.com/2014/02/03/convert-a-wim-or-iso-file-to-vhdx/).

Notes: Your ISO should then contain an operating system that directly gets an IP address via DHCP and has open ports for remote access. Otherwise you cannot access it.

Then, you could upload the VHD to Azure storage account and use the VHD to create Azure VMs. More steps please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-upload-image).

Comment: HI - run into a prob. Powersjhell installed, permissions set etc. to run the script. I run the script with the .\Convert-WindowsImage.ps1 -showui options - nothing happens. I am asked if I want to run the script, I type R for run once and then nada.... I am running Win 10 in  Parallels VM on a MAC.

Comment: Do you get VHD file?

Comment: After you covert your image to VHD, you need prepare your VM by using Hyper-V. Please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-linux-create-upload-centos?toc=%2fazure%2fvirtual-machines%2flinux%2ftoc.json).